# Google Maps app loads to emulator but will not open on emulator

Tags: android, maps

I followed the google maps tutorial to create a new google maps project, obtained an api key, included the , and the INTERNET permissions in the manifest file. Included

in the main.xml file, and followed the steps to modify the main.java file. The app will install to the emulator, but as soon as I click on the app, a notifications shows:
The application has stopped unexpectedly.

I have exhausted all resources, so hopefully someone can help. Thanks in advance for all of the help. Also, in the logcat, I am getting a number of errors after I "click" on the app in the emulator. One error in particular that I have read about, but not found a fix for is:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hutzley.TestMap.MyApplication in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader

Comment: You'll probably need to provide all the errors. Often one is caused by another, and can only be understood by identifying the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Something in your app is trying to refer to `com.hutzley.TestMap.MyApplication`, and this class does not exist in your project. Since a reference from Java would typically generate a compile error, I recommend that you check your manifest, find where this is referenced, and change it to whatever it is supposed to be.

Comment: Or maybe the class does exist in the project, but cannot be loaded on the device (in turn refers to something that is missing?)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using one of the special emulator images which supports the Google APIs, without this you would be trying to run your app on an environment that lacks required libraries for maps to work.